# Child or Nexted objects Json.NET

Tags: json.net

Very simply I need to serialize an object using json.net to produce json that looks like this:

```
{
   "Auth":{
      "Phone":"5555555555",
      "Username":"JoePUser",
      "Password":"password"
   },
   "Request":{
      "Module":"membership",
      "Section":"directory",
      "Filters":{
         "startAt":0,
         "limit":10
      },
      "Sort":{
         "last_name":"ascending",
         "first_name":"ascending"
      }
   }
}
```

I cannot get the nested or child items to format properly.  I honestly do not know what the proper term is for them.  A nod in the right direction would be wonderful!  Appreciate any help!

Randy

Comment: so which technology you'll use to serialize those stuff?

Comment: Assuming you are using c#, you can 1) go to http://json2csharp.com/; 2) Paste your JSON in; 3) Get appropriate classes back. 4) Now you can do [`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString)`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject.htm).  Is that all you need?

Comment: What language are you using?  c#?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: What do your classes look like?

Comment: _I cannot get the nested or child items to format properly_ --> how do they format, and why is it not proper ?